# Insert automatically creating and retrieving existing data in one command

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

i  have below entities in java

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
 
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Adress> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
 
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
}
```

so lets say i have in database one address with id = 1, now I would like to create in HQL (or SQL) an insert who would let me create a new person with address got from database with id = 1 in one command. Is it even possible? Or am i forced to do it in a few commands? I would be very gratefull for every help thank you

Comment: you need to insert both the person, and the address - 2 individual commands.

Comment: In SQL it will be `insert into person (name, addresses) select 'Some name', address from address where id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

That's not really possible with your model as the FK for the relationship is on the address table. What you can do to reduce the overhead is this:

```
Person p = new Person();
entityManager.persist(p);
entityManager.createQuery("update Address a set a.person = :p where a.id = :id")
    .setParameter("p", p)
    .setParameter("id", 1)
    .executeUpdate();
```